# Remove sqlite locking in SVN

Tags: svn, sqlite

I am using svn 1.8 server and client version. We have some huge repositories for which checkout takes quite a long time in a distributed file system. Thinking of performing parallel checkouts to reduce the checkout time. However, svn 1.8 doesn't support parallel checkouts as the sqlite db inside .svn folder will be locked and will allow only one write operation at a time. Is there any way I can remove the sqlite locking to allow parallel checkouts?

Comment: The locking prevents database corruption.

Comment: Agree. There is any option to update the DB in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite [has no write concurrency](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5), and this is inherent in its design (a single database-wide lock).
And Subversion cannot use any other database for the working copy metadata.

You could try to reduce the locking overhead by a small amount by enabling [exclusive locking](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#exclusivelocking).

However, the easiest way to change the checkout behaviour would be to switch to another version control system like git.

Comment: Thanks for the update CL. My svn repository size is close to 900 GB. Does git support that big repositories? Cloning wouldn't be a problem?